# Praeter et Supra, Si non Vires

Tags: latin-to-english-translation, medieval-latin

How does my translation of this passage look, especially with respect to the bolded section(s)?

Modestia in cultu ornatuque corporis, **praeter & supra**, **si non vires**, saltem dignitatem moribus patriae convenientem, & infirmorum scandalis non obnoxiam. Haec imprimis praecipitur feminis & virginibus, quia ad ornandum & comendum se procliviores esse solent, & **excusationem mereri sibi videntur** ob **infirmitatis propriae** conscientiam, & **in virorum procorumve gratiam.**

Modesty in the decoration and attire of the body, if not over and above one’s powers, at least [over and above] a dignity which is becoming of the morals of one’s nation and not guilty of the temptations of the weak. This modesty is prescribed especially to women and young women because they are often inclined to dress and adorn themselves, and [because] they seem to be entitled to an excuse in their own eyes on account of a consciousness of their own infirmity, and for the sake of men or suitors if you will.